# Unit testing a NestJS controller that has a bunch of imports

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, nestjs

I'm trying to unit test a NestJS health-check controller. The health module has a few imports (see code below).

I need to mock the `HttpModule` so that I can test the scenario where the `payments-service` **is down** and another scenario where the `payments-service` **is up**.

I'm struggling to achieve that.

**CODE**

*health.module.ts*

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TerminusModule } from '@nestjs/terminus';
import { HealthController } from './health.controller';
import { HttpModule } from '@nestjs/axios';
import { AppConfigModule } from '@app-config/app-config.module';

@Module({
  imports: [TerminusModule, HttpModule, AppConfigModule],
  controllers: [HealthController],
})
export class HealthModule {}
```

*health.controller.ts*

```
import { Controller, Get, InternalServerErrorException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { HealthCheck, HealthCheckService, HttpHealthIndicator } from '@nestjs/terminus';
import { ApiOperation, ApiTags } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import * as moment from 'moment';
import { AppConfigService } from '@app-config/app-config-service/app-config.service';
import { HealthCheckResult } from '@nestjs/terminus/dist/health-check/health-check-result.interface';

@ApiTags('health')
@Controller('health')
export class HealthController {
  static readonly HEALTH_CHECK_FREQ = 30; // in seconds
  private healthExpiry = moment();
  private isHealthy = true;
  private healthCheckResult: HealthCheckResult;

  constructor(
    private health: HealthCheckService,
    private http: HttpHealthIndicator,
    private configService: AppConfigService
  ) {
    this.check = this.check.bind(this);
  }

  @Get()
  @ApiOperation({ summary: 'Checks the status of the service' })
  @HealthCheck()
  async check(): Promise<HealthCheckResult> {
    const now = moment();
    if (this.healthExpiry.isBefore(now)) {
      console.info('Checking server health...');
      const paymentsHost = this.configService.env.rooster.paymentsService.host;

      try {
        this.healthCheckResult = await this.health.check([
          async () => await this.http.pingCheck('payments-service', `https://${paymentsHost}/health`),
        ]);

        if (this.healthCheckResult.status === 'ok') {
          this.isHealthy = true;
        } else {
          this.isHealthy = false;
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        this.isHealthy = false;
      }

      this.healthExpiry = now.add(HealthController.HEALTH_CHECK_FREQ, 'seconds');
      console.info('server health:', this.isHealthy);
    }

    if (!this.isHealthy) {
      throw new InternalServerErrorException(this.healthCheckResult);
    }

    return this.healthCheckResult;
  }
}
```

*health.controller.spec.ts*

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { HealthController } from './health.controller';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import MockEnvConfig from '../../test/resources/MockEnvConfig';
import { AppConfigModule } from '@app-config/app-config.module';
import { TerminusModule } from '@nestjs/terminus';
import { HttpService } from '@nestjs/axios';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

// mock services to avoid loading actual aws app config and ssm params
jest.mock('@rooster/node-services');

describe('HealthController', () => {
  let controller: HealthController;
  // @ts-ignore
  let httpService: HttpService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [
        ConfigModule.forRoot({
          ignoreEnvVars: true,
          ignoreEnvFile: true,
          load: [MockEnvConfig],
        }),
        AppConfigModule,
        TerminusModule,
      ],
      controllers: [HealthController],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: HttpService,
          useValue: {
            get: jest.fn(() => of({ 'payments-service': { status: 'up' } })),
            request: jest.fn(() => of({ status: 'ok' })),
          },
        },
      ],
    }).compile();

    controller = module.get<HealthController>(HealthController);
    httpService = module.get<HttpService>(HttpService);
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(controller).toBeDefined();
  });

  describe('checkHealth()', () => {
    it('should return happy result', async () => {
      const happyResult = {
        status: 'ok',
        info: { 'payments-service': { status: 'up' } },
        error: {},
        details: { 'payments-service': { status: 'up' } },
      };

      await expect(controller.check()).resolves.toEqual(happyResult);
    });
  });
});
```

**UPDATE**

I made some changes to code, and I got much closer. The test now **passes intermittently**. In other words, sometimes the test passes, and sometimes it fails.

Here's a screenshot:

[image: test passing and failing]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your spec file, you are importing real module instead of mocking it. Your controller uses `HttpService` so you need to mock it instead of importing it:

```js
describe('HealthController', () => {
  let controller: HealthController;
  let httpService : HttpService ;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [
        ConfigModule.forRoot({
          ignoreEnvVars: true,
          ignoreEnvFile: true,
          load: [MockEnvConfig],
        }),
        AppConfigModule,
        TerminusModule,
        // HttpModule, DO NOT IMPORT IT
      ],
      controllers: [HealthController],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: HttpService
          useValue: {
            get: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue('some result');
          }
        }
    }).compile();

    controller = module.get<HealthController>(HealthController);           
    httpService = module.get<HttpService>(HttpService);
  });
```

Now with those changes you can check if for example `get` method has been called:

```js
  describe('checkHealth()', () => {
    it('should return happy result', async () => {
      await expect(controller.check()).resolves.toBe('OK'); // might need to change the 'OK'
      expect(httpService.get).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
```

Comment: hmm I get an error: Property 'get' does not exist on healthcheckservice! [See screenshot](https://imgur.com/70BCwri)

Comment: Oh sorry I mixed up `HttpService` with `HealthCheckService`, Fixed now.

Comment: hmm weirdly it still fails. [See screenshot](https://imgur.com/mYNtrlD). If it had failed by saying `Ok` isn't equal to `some result`, then I'd know what to do, but it is returning `undefined` which I'm confused about

Comment: That's because you have to also mock other providers like `HealthCheckService` because you are using its `check` method. What I write was an example to show you how can you mock a dependency. You can do the same thing for `HealthCheckService.check()`.

Comment: ah I got you, thanks, let me give it a try

Comment: Even though, I mocked everything that I think needed mocking, the test still won't pass reliably. See updated question